Which client is used from vim.lsp.formatexpr() when multiple clients attached in a buffer on Neovim?
Now nvim-lspconfig sets 'formatexpr' to v:lua.vim.lsp.formatexpr().
But the help for that function says that supports only a single client.
formatexpr({opts})                                      *vim.lsp.formatexpr()*
    Provides an interface between the built-in client and a `formatexpr`
    function.

    Currently only supports a single client. This can be set via
    `setlocal formatexpr=v:lua.vim.lsp.formatexpr()` but will typically or in
    `on_attach` via
    `vim.bo[bufnr].formatexpr = 'v:lua.vim.lsp.formatexpr(#{timeout_ms:250})'`.

    Parameters: ~
      • {opts}  (`table?`) A table with the following fields:
                • {timeout_ms} (`integer`, default: 500ms) The timeout period
                  for the formatting request..

Which client is used from vim.lsp.formatexpr() when multiple clients attached in a buffer?
